# How to maintain login user details in angular app

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

How can I maintain the login user details in angular app, the data is lost when to reloading the app, how to resolve this problem, my server side is nodejs

Comment: What do you use for authentification? You have tokens?

Comment: No, simple api call it returns  the user id

Comment: Then use either cookies or browser storage (session or local) but you will have next to zero security.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the logged user details ,like username email, and any other details in local storage. and remove this storage on logout.

2nd and most important is  that you server API interaction may ask some sessionID, or equivalent key for trusted actions. you might want that.

Comment: Yes, if it is mobile app. and may be if its browser. but in case you are concerned about security then either encrypt it using MD5.  or store minimum info. and retrieve remaining from server.

Comment: Use $cookies instead of localstorage if you are concerned about security

Answer (score 0):

After login I am saving the details in `$cookies`, like the token, user-name etc. Here is the code:-

```
$cookies.put('token', response.token);
$cookies.put('user', response.user);
```

I am putting these things in the success block of service call.

And you can delete them on logout like this:-

```
$cookies.remove('token');
$cookies.remove('user');
```

Every website is using `$cookies` these days even facebook.